# POST to /likes only works after GET - bug or by design?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

My app has permissions to "like" something on FB on a user's behalf. Using the Facebook C# SDK (5.4.1), here's what I wrote:

```
Facebook.FacebookClient fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(AccessToken);
object o = fb.Get("1234567890_12345678901234567/likes");
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
dynamic success = fb.Post("1234567890_12345678901234567/likes", parameters);
```

The second line is superfluous and creates an unnecessary round-trip, as we're not interested in the other "likes" on the same object. However, without it, fb.Post fails and throws "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Is this a bug in the C# SDK, or a bug in the graph API, or is it by design?

Note that it's possible to POST to /comments without a previous GET.

Comment: This might be related to this issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598614/facebook-c-sharp-api-return-400-when-deauthorizing-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible to do post commands without a get.  Strangely enough, my like code with the 5.4.1 does not require the extra GET directly before the POST for doing a like.  Maybe somewhere else in my app's flow I've already done some sort of GET via the API.  However, I'm going to investigate my DELETE problem with `me/permissions` that I'm encountering (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598614/facebook-c-sharp-api-return-400-when-deauthorizing-app) and see if a get to the me/permissions first will help resolve that issue.

Comment: Yet another person is reporting this issue too:  http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8887113/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-recommend-post-using-access-token  You two should get together and file a bug with the C# SDK people.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Good idea, filed an issue with the Facebook C# SDK: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/5929